# I want to keep the select option selected once i submitted the form. I'm using Laravel 7 with Bootstrap

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-7

Here's the View Code:
also I'm passing the variable to be selected by compact, but this technique does'nt work

```html
<select class="form-control" name="month">
    @foreach ($cement_cmonths as $cement_cmonth)
        <option {{$month == $cement_cmonth->cmonth ? "selected" : ""}} value=" 
        {{$cement_cmonth->cmonth}}">{{$cement_cmonth->cmonth}}</option>
    @endforeach 
</select>
```

The `$month` is the selected variable to remain selected, i'm passing it through compact.

Comment: check the value of variable $month using dd($month), u need to debug it as your view code is looking ok.

Comment: it's printing correctly

Comment: Your `$month == $cement_cmonth->cmonth` is failing. Are you comparing `strings` or `numerics`?

Comment: I'm using strings

Comment: Have you confirmed using some debugging that `$month` and `$cement_cmonth->cmonth` are actually the same and what you expect?

Comment: Obviously there is no issue where your code, please double check your data.

Comment: Hi. if you are sure about your data use `strcasecmp` function to compare your strings.
`strcasecmp($month, $cement_cmonth->cmonth) == 0 ? 'selected' : ''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditional is failing:

```
{{ $month == $cement_cmonth->cmonth ? "selected" : "" }}
```

The above is not evaluating to `true` hence the `selected` attribute not being applied to any of your `option`s.

This means your `$month` and `$cement_cmonth->cmonth` values are not equal. This could be because they are genuinely not the same `('jan' != 'feb')` or it could be the values are the same but the casing differs.

As you are using `strings` you need to be careful of character casing as `==` is case sensitive.

The following evaluates to false:

```
'jan' == 'Jan'
```

To avoid this issue, use [`strcasecmp`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php):

```
{{ strcasecmp($month, $cement_cmonth->cmonth) === 0 ? "selected" : "" }}
```